# How to do a reflection in a while loop without initializing it

Tags: java, reflection, methods, initialization, invoke

```
      Method method;


         try {
            method = m.getClass().getMethod(h);
            } catch (SecurityException e) {

            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {

            }


         try {
              //line below wants me to initialize it
              method.invoke(m);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {

            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {

            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            }
```

This code is in a while loop. When I sett Method method to null i get a null point exception. How can I make my code run in my while loop.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If there is an exception in the first `try{}` block then your variable `method` doesn't get initialized. That's why you get a compile error.

Try this:

```
public
class ReflectiveCall
{
    public static
    void main(String args[])
    {
        ReflectiveCall m = new ReflectiveCall();
        String h = "foo";

        while (true)
        {
            Method method;
            try
            {
                method = m.getClass().getMethod(h);                   
                method.invoke(m);
            }
            catch (SecurityException e)
            {
            }
            catch (NoSuchMethodException e)
            {
            }
            catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
            {
            }
            catch (IllegalAccessException e)
            {
            }
            catch (InvocationTargetException e)
            {
            }
        }
    }

    public
    void foo()
    {
        System.out.println("foo");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

firstly never silently ignore exceptions.  In this case if you catch and ignore the first exceptions, then `method` will be `null`